Spider identification?
enter image description here

Can someone help me identify this spider? I've never seen one like this. I have brown widows and brown recluses in my yard, along with different types of orb weavers, but I have never seen this one before. There are also a lot of different house spiders and jumping spiders of all kinds. This one was huge though. This is the underside of the belly, I couldn't get a shot of the top. I'm in Southern California.

Looks like the underside of a female silver argiope, a.k.a. silver garden spider (Argiope argentata).
